# Monitoring of dynamic integration flows

Tags: spring-integration, monitoring, spring-boot-actuator

I am building the pollers based on the data from the database. Mainly file pollers.

Does Spring integration provide any way to monitor the flows via the spring admin /actuator?

If yes, is there any example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, need to understand what you mean with the *monitor*.

There is an `/integrationgraph` since Spring Boot 2.1 endpoint to show all the integration components in the application context as a JSON graph. You have enable it explicitly though: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-endpoints-exposing-endpoints.

There is also an endpoint for metrics to obtain: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready-metrics-meter

Comment: Sorry I was not clear. Basically I want to see what flows are running and if I want to expose some data which can be viewable from the UI.

Comment: OK. So, I think Integration Graph is for you. Also see Spring Integration Docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/system-management-chapter.html#integration-graph

Comment: Thanks a lot . It is something I was looking for.